# Chop down function arguments, but keep as-is if one argument is a multi line array and line is not to long

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I have been playing with all the PhpStorm formatting options, but can't find a way to have if behave the way I want.

So basically I want PhpStorm to:

**1. turn this**:

```php
myfunction('hello',
    'world');
```

Into this:

```php
myfunction(
    'hello',
    'world'
);
```

**2. keep this as is**:

```php
myfunction([
    'hello' => 'world',
]);
```

Also this shouldn't be reformatted:

```php
myfunction($variableOne, [
    'hello' => 'world',
]);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know at this moment it is impossible.

Now to get this ability

```
myfunction([
    'hello' => 'world',
]);

myfunction($variableOne, [
    'hello' => 'world',
]);
```

you can setup options in this position:

[image]

But to setup wrapping on different params in new line

```
myfunction(
    'hello',
    'world'
);
```

you need another option list:

[image]

But in this case wrapping of array doesn't consist with your conditions.

Leave your feature request on [JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/). Only they can help you with this feature.

You need some option like `Don't wrap array declaration`.

But also you have one collision in condition: 
if you want arguments on new line in this case

```
myfunction(
    'hello',
    'world'
);
```

why you don't want it this?

```
myfunction(
    $variableOne, [
        'hello' => 'world',
    ]
);

myfunction(
    [
        'hello' => 'world',
    ]
);
```

Or even maybe you need option like `Leave array declaration braces with comma/brace in method call`. In that case it would work in way like

```
myfunction($variableOne, [
    'hello' => 'world',
]);

myfunction([
    'hello' => 'world',
]);
```

But here you also need some option like `Don't wrap argument if it no long and contain array declaration`.

IMHO the best way to resolve this issue is leave feature request with well describe rules of wrapping like what to do in next cases

```
myfunction($variableOne, $variableTwo, [
    'hello' => 'world',
]);

myfunction($variableOne, $variableTwo, [
    'hello' => 'world',
], [
    'another' => 'array',
]);
```

Also what to do with PHP 5.3- array declaration `array('key' => 'value')` in method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, this is what I feared, there is no way to do what I want at the moment. I'll fill in a feature request.

Comment: FYI: These settings are under File => Settings => Editor => Code Style => PHP(or other language)

Comment: @jave.web, feel free to edit my answer and add that info inside it 